# Increase memory vs number of dynamos for Heroku?

Tags: heroku, prisma

Ive deployed Prisma to Heroku: https://www.prisma.io/blog/heroku-integration-homihof6eifi/

The only traffic to my site is myself testing it. I started out with 1 hobby dynamo but the 'resting' memory usage was around 95% and I'm was getting some "Memory quota exceeded" errors.

To try and fix this I increased the dynamo count to 2. Im now paying $50 per month.

Despite this Im still getting memory usage warnings. $50 a month for a service thats struggling with very low traffic seems crazy. Have I set something up wrong? Should I have increased the memory limit rather than number of dynamos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A future release of Prisma will introduce significant improvements to memory handling. While operating Prisma on a 512 mb dyno is certainly possible, you will currently have a much better experience upgrading to a 1024 mb dyno. Running a single large dyno will provide a much bigger improvement than running two small dynos.

Hope this helps :-)